# Scipy imsave darken my image

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I'm doing image processing and am working with Python 2.7 in a Jupyter Notebook.
But when I save a numpy array as an image with `scipy.misc.imsave()`, the result appears **darker** than when I visualize it with matplotlib.

Here is the result when I plot the image in my notebook :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot    
plot.imshow(img)
```

[image]

And here is the image when I save it :

```
scipy.misc.imsave(img, 'img.png')
```

[image]

The image appears darker than it should be and I have no idea why. Has someone ever faced a similar problem ?

Comment: It looks to me that there is an alpha channel added, could it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is because imsave() normalizes the image between min and max values.

You can do this:

```
scipy.misc.toimage(img, cmin=0, cmax=255).save('img.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that some of my images have values <0, the solution is to clip them between 0 and 255 and the saved image is now correct. But I still don't know why the plot shows them correctly